# What exactly counts as using AJAX

Tags: ajax

From my understanding, AJAX requires the use of the XMLHttpRequest object. What I am confused on is the source of where the XMLHttpRequest object is connected to? In the school projects, I have connected it to XML and mySQL and was told that I am doing AJAX. What if I connect the XMLHttpRequest object to a PHP script which contains an array of data? Would that count as AJAX?

The reason why I ask is because I was thinking of adding AJAX to my resume, but since this area seems so broad and I have had limited experience with it, I want to make sure I have a clear understanding of this technology.

Comment: This might be closed as off topic, I would try to put it in programmers.stackexchange.com, p.s. if you use it with JSON, it's AJAJ

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The AJAX part is just how the request is made from the client.  If it happens asynchronously using XmlHttpRequest, it doesn't matter where the request is going :-) It could be a request to an server side script in PHP, a JSON file, an xml file, or anything else.

Answer (score 1):

It's not broad at all. Any time you do an async web request (actually, it doesn't even have to be async, but that's really the best way to to use it) via javascript (rather than through a Form submit) you're using AJAX. What you connect to or what you retrieve is irrelevant.

Without being rude, I'd like to point out that if you state on a resume that you possess "a clear understanding of this technology" then you're not being honest, since you're asking this question, which indicates that your understanding of the technology isn't "clear".

If, however, you're totally confortable with the use of Ajax and were simply not entirely clear on it's lexical definition... well... now you should be.

Answer (score 1):

yes ,the ajax can used for all language,soever java or asp and php